# Android image animation

Tags: android, animation, renderscript

i am trying to implement an animated butterfly which should fly around the screen by clicking a button .How can i implement it efficiently.If i need multiple butterflies(may be 100+) whether it effect device performance?.How can i achieve fly effect on wings.

1. Is it possible to implement with many parts of a butterfly image put
   together and bring this fly effect.
2. Can i use renderScript

Please provide a sample code.i tried scaled animation but it is not as expected .any help appreciable.

Comment: Does this help ? http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/frame-by-frame-animation-tutorial.html

Comment: hi @Mrad Mrad, that tutorial is good but how can i implement that object randomly fly around on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a quite good performance with showing a simple gif in your layout. Just create a gif out of the images you have (use some [gif maker](http://gifmaker.me) for that - there are a ton of other options, just search for it). For showing the gif in your application you can use a custom library, like [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/android-gif-drawable). Implementation is similar to an ImageView:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/your_butterfly_anim"
/>
```

It's a possibility for simple animations.

Edit:

```
int distance = 100; //the distance to move in pixels
int duration = 500; //the duration of the animation in ms

double direction = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

int translationX = Math.cos(direction) * distance;
int translationY = Math.sin(direction) * distance;

yourImageView.animate().translationX(translationX).translationY(translationY).setDuration(duration).start();
```

This should give you some first ideas of how you can get it flying randomly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help

Comment: hi ,david i want to move that object randomly on screen see my question

Comment: I didn't worked a lot with animations in Android, but you could try to use a [view animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) on the gifImageView - think you could achieve some good results with that.

Comment: can you suggest any example

Comment: i need to add many  gif images into my view at random place and it should float around screen

Comment: these libraries consume lot of memory too

Comment: That's true, it's good for single or a few gifs. I use them in a recycle view and it works quite good.

Comment: yep, complex lists and card views.

Comment: yeah but in  my case i have only one root view wish should hold all those animation